# Why would the cubic have $5$ roots?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> The polynomial $P(x)$ is cubic. What is the largest value of $k$ for which the polynomials $Q_{1}(x) = x^{2}+(k-29)x-k$ and $Q_{2}(x) = 2x^{2}+(2k-43)x+k$ are both factors of $P(x)$?

$P(x) = (x-c)(Q_1(x))$ and $P(x) = (x-t)Q_2(x)$

The solution $P(x)$ has both these as factors if they have a common factor.

I have a issue here:

Let $Q_1(x) = (x-a)(x-b)$ and $Q_2(x) = (x-a)(x-f)$. Then

$P(x) = (x-c)(x-a)(x-b)$ and $P(x) = (x-t)(x-a)(x-f)$

Meaning it has roots: $\{a, b, c, t, f\}$ that is five roots!

and if $t=c$ that isnt possible because $Q_1(x) = Q_2(x)$ then.

Take the same roots again, is it possible that:

$P(x) = (x-f)Q_1(x)$ and $P(x) = (x-b)Q_2(x)$?

Then the roots are: $\{f,a, b\}$

Which meaning is implied?

Comment: Where does it say that all those $5$ roots are distinct?

Comment: What if b=t and c=f?

Comment: As to solving the original problem: if $x$ is the common root of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ then this is also a root of $Q_2(x) - 2Q_1(x)$ which is a linear polynomial.

Comment: I'm far from an expert on algebra, so I could be misunderstanding the fundamental theorem of algebra: if $P(x)$ is cubic then it only has three roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $k$ qualifies, you will necessarily have $b=t$ and $c=f$, so the apparently five roots are only three!

Answer (score 0):

First note that $Q_2$ is not normed. Thus, it cannot be of the form $(x-a)(x-f)$. 
But rather $2(x-a)(x-f)$.

Second, it is (thus) also possible (at least in principle) that both roots of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are the same.

In any case you will always have three roots of $P$ (with multiplicity), and thus $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ must have at least one root in common.

Put differently the polynomial gcd of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ is not constant. 
To solve the problem compute the gcd of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, and see for which $k$ it can be non-constant.